# Call function with gravity forms button submit

Tags: jquery, gravity-forms-plugin

I have a button that calls a function

```
<input class="cta" type="button" value="Next" onClick="Javascript: BankAccountValidation_Interactive_Validate_v2_00Begin('AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA', document.getElementById('input_43_29').value, document.getElementById('input_43_30').value)">
```

Instead of using this button to call the function, I want to target the next button on a gravity forms form to call the function instead

```
<input type="button" id="gform_next_button_43_55" class="gform_next_button button" value="Next" tabindex="13" onclick="jQuery(&quot;#gform_target_page_number_43&quot;).val(&quot;3&quot;); jQuery(&quot;#gform_43&quot;).trigger(&quot;submit&quot;,[true]); " style="display: block;">
```

How do I call the BankAccountValidation_Interactive_Validate_v2_00Begin function on click of #gform_next_button_43_55?

So far I have:

```
$(function() {
  $("#gform_next_button_43_55").click( function()
       {

       }
  );
});
```